# Expressing ideals as products of prime ideals in a commutative, Noetherian ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative, Noetherian ring with unity.  I know that the following is true:

> For any ideal $I\subset R$, there are prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_n$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n\subset I$.

If we only consider proper ideals, can we always find prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_n$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n=I$?

I came across this problem on an old qualifying exam and it has me puzzled.  I'm beginning to think the problem is stated incorrectly.  Are there any counterexamples, or is the result true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example in the ring $R=k[x,y]$, the ideal $I=(x,y^2)$ is $P$-primary, where $P = (x, y)$, but is not a power of $P$, so the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: This is helpful, but if we know $I$ is not a power of $P$, why can we conclude it is not the product of any prime ideals?  I'm not too familiar with properties of $P$-primary ideals.

Comment: In our case $\sqrt I=P$. If $I=\mathfrak{p}_1\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n$ what about $\sqrt I$?

Comment: @Jared But why does $P = \mathfrak{p}_1 \cap \ldots \mathfrak{p}_n$ force $\mathfrak{p}_i = P$ for *all* $i$?  Couldn't you have a single $\mathfrak{p}_i = P$ and all the other $\mathfrak{p}$'s being prime ideals strictly bigger than $P$?  You have to use the fact that $I$ is primary somehow, not just that $\sqrt{I}$ is prime.  It is *not* true that if $\sqrt{I}$ is prime, and $I$ is expressed as the product of prime ideals, then all those prime ideals are equal.  For example, $I=(x^2,xy)$ has prime radical $(x)$ and can be written as the product of distinct primes: $I=(x)(x,y)$.

Comment: @Ted In our case $P$ is maximal and this makes things very simple.

Comment: Yes that's true. But is the original claim correct, that if $I$ is primary and expressed as a product of prime ideals, then all the primes are equal?

Answer (score 0):

A commutative ring $R$ with unity is said to be a *general zpi ring* if every ideal of $R$ is a finite product of prime ideals.

Examples: 1) $\Bbb Z$ is a general zpi ring; 2) $\Bbb Z[[X]]$ is noetherian but not a general zpi ring.

Therefore the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Why 'zpi'? Do you have a reference for these facts?

Comment: @ Michael Albanese you can see this paper "ON GENERAL Z.P.I.-RINGS"
CRAIG A. WOOD